# UITextView issue - caret jumps upwards

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitextview

I have a UIViewController with a UITextView as its subview. Its as simple a hierarchy as that. When I tap inside the textview, the caret(cursor) jumps upwards by 10 px as if the return key was hit magically and whatever I type is there but gives a clipped look. What could be the reason? Any fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Solves the caret jump issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on iOS 8. When manually update .attributedText property of the textView together with .selectedRange (to move the caret), the caret jumps upwards for a moment and then comes back where it supposed to be. The solution with setting contentInset to UIEdgeInsetsZero didn't work for me. In my case, the solution was to set:

```
_textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

2019: I had similar issue for iPhoneX+ after disabling contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior the issue is resolved.

```
textView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```